# How to properly close FIFO (named pipe) used in an infinite loop, when program terminates?

Tags: c, named-pipes, fifo

I'm using named pipes in a multi-process program that write/read on/from the pipes in an infinite loop and do something. I know that those FDs have to be closed before exiting the program to keep them work properly, but in this case how to do it?

(By terminating I mean from a master process, from a CTRL+C ecc..)

Here is a sketch of the code (**writer**):

```
....    
  open(myfifo,O_WRONLY)
  while(1){
       //GET COMMAND FROM INPUT
       fgets(buffer, 80, stdin);
       write(myfifo, buffer, 81);
  }
}
```

and here's the **reader**:

```
....
last_command = "0";
open(myfifo,O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)
while(1){
     //IF SOMETHING HAS BEEN WRITTEN, TAKE IT
     if (read(myfifo, buffer, 81)>0){
          last_command = buffer;
     }
     do_something(last_command);
}
}
```

I hope it's clear.

Comment: test return values for read/write calls, this will helps you to determine when you should exit loops.

Comment: I don't get you. If I send a SIGINT for example when it is inside 'do_something', they will end without testing read/write calls.

Comment: For sure, but then you need to catch signals and do something either to break the loops or clean things and exit.

Comment: I guessed something like this, thank you, but how to do this? Moreover, your first answer doesn't have sense to me after this..